# How much space is really available for your Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows-10, powershell, hyper-v

By googleing the headline you can find a lot how-tos out there. I fail to follow most tutorials, because there are not that many entries under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest`. Especially no entry `Parameters`:

[image]

Comment: Is the question about getting the host name from the VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With powershell, enter to get the list of VM(s):

```PS
Get-VM
```

then use [Measure-VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/measure-vm?view=windowsserver2019-ps):

```PS
Measure-VM -VMName YourVM
```

Note from [Measure-VM description](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/measure-vm?view=windowsserver2019-ps#:%7E:text=Description-,The%20Measure-VM%20cmdlet,for%20a%20virtual%20machine.,-The%20report%20has):

> The Measure-VM cmdlet reports data on processor usage, memory usage, network traffic, and disk capacity for one or more virtual machines.
>
> Note: Data is available for reporting through the Measure-VM cmdlet only after resource metering is enabled for a virtual machine.

Comment: Thx, `Measure-VM` returns a TotalDisk size of 70848. In addition to my question, does this comes from my checkpoint? HyperV-Manager shows me a current file size of 14GB. If I want to work further with 50GB, then I have to delete or merge my checkpoint? And does this also effects my disk space in the Guest-VM, which is ~30GB at the moment.

Comment: @Hölderlin According to Measure-VM notes: "The disk capacity allocated to the virtual machine is reported as the sum of two totals -- the total storage capacity of all attached virtual hard disks, and the total amount of physical storage consumed by the virtual machine's snapshots"

Comment: @Hölderlin Unfortunately, I won't be much of a help. Let hope others can answer your last questions.